# ActionBarDrawerToggle from right and left side using Navigation Drawer & ActionBarSherLock

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to implement Right and Left Side Sliding Menu so I am using `Navigation Drawer` to for Left side `ListView` and Right Side `ListView`.

I have set code and It is working fine. But right now, Situation is like there is only one `NavigationDrawerIcon` which is at Left side and by Clicking on it, I am getting both side Slider.
But I want to Display `NavigationDrawerIcon` at Right and Left Side both. So, how to do it ?